# Sending Oracle database record using https request to Google form with no internet permission of oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am facing this problem in getting the new, update or deleted record from table in Oracle database to prefilled Google Form.

The Oracle database is with disabled permission to access the internet (ACL list) and according to recommendations that this is the best practice for Oracle databases.

I have managed to write some triggers in PL/SQL, but still no permission.

I have searched the internet, but I have not found anything that can help me with this scenario.

What I am thinking is to create a new Oracle database on the same server but with HTTPS permission access, using trigger on the old database to copy the record to the new database and a trigger on the new database to submit the record to Google form.

I have tried this idea, but each time I try to create new database I get errors.

So please, if you have other ideas in solving this issue, or helping with applying the scenario that I am thinking of.

My knowledge in Oracle databases is very shallow and their documentation from my point of view is that your topic is distributed under different chapters and sections which accumulate the felling of doubt that you are not in the right place the more you read in these sections.

Comment: You need to get with your DBA to create the ACL for your procedure. You would need to do that anyway if creating a new database; network access cannot be enabled by default. If there is a _reason_ that internet access is not allowed, then they should also be able to explain that to you.

Comment: Yes I mean network access and not internet access. For BDA does not exist as he build the DB and left longtime ago, but still the system is useful and need to add new features this what I am trying to do as G suite admin

Comment: You need an ACL for any kind of stored procedure access to the network. Creating a new database won't help. You need someone with DBA-level access and knowledge of seeing up ACLs.

Comment: [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1) may be useful.  You did not specify what version of oracle you are using, as there have been changes since 11g. Now called ACE

Comment: Could you please edit your question? There are some grammar and punctuation issues that make it a slow read.